# Can you provide us an asymptotic for this series involving Mertens functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

Let for integers $k\geq 1$, the **Möbius function** denoted by $\mu(k)$, and $M(n)=\sum_{k\leq n}\mu(k)$ the **Mertens function**, then one can prove easily that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)\frac{e^{\mu(k)}+1}{e^{\mu(k)}-1}=M(n)+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{e^{\mu(k)}-1}.$$

I've used the first identity in the proof of **Proposition 6.9.1**, page 130 of George **Boros** and Victor **Moll**, *Irresistible integrals. Symbolic, Analysis and Experiments in the Evaluation of Integrals*, Cambridge (2004).

> **Fact.** **The graphs** of the arithmetic functions $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)\frac{e^{\mu(k)}+1}{e^{\mu(k)}-1}$ and $g(n)=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{e^{\mu(k)}-1}$ *have slopes very well defined.*

My

> **Question.** It is possible obtain the asymptotic behaviour (you can work with the **asymptotic equivalence** $\sim$ or some **oh notation**) for some of previous arithmetica functions? I say or well for $f(n)$ or for $g(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ (truly the graphs of these functions *seems the same*). **THanks in advance.**

Comment: One can also do experiments as take different linear combinations of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$, also take the absolute value of such function $f(n)$ or $g(n)$. If this question is interesting for you feel free to take as yourself task, share... Thanks.

Comment: Was the identity that is implicit, combining with that for $n$ such that $\mu(n)=0$. Also there was a typo, fixed. Very thanks much @user1952009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you meant $\mu(k) \frac{e^{\mu(k)}+1}{e^{\mu(k)}-1} = 0$ when $\mu(k) = 0$ :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k) \frac{e^{\mu(k)}+1}{e^{\mu(k)}-1} = \frac{e+1}{e-1} \sum_{k\le n, \mu(k) = 1} 1  -\frac{e^{-1}+1}{e^{-1}-1} \sum_{k\le n, \mu(k) = -1} 1 $$ $$= \frac{e+1}{e-1} \sum_{k\le n, \mu(k) = 1} 1 -\frac{1+e}{1-e} \sum_{k\le n, \mu(k) = -1} 1 = \frac{e+1}{e-1} \sum_{k=1}^n |\mu(k)| \sim\frac{e+1}{e-1} \frac{6}{\pi^2} n $$

the last asymptotics being because $$\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \prod_p \frac{1-p^{-2s}}{1-p^{-s}} = \prod_p 1+p^{-s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(n)| n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \sum_{n \le x} |\mu(n)|x^{-s-1}dx$$
is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients, converging absolutely for $Re(s) > 1$ and with a pole of order $1$ and residue $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ at $s=1$

Comment: Very thanks much for your calculations! You are great and very quickly. This afternoon I was studying, and I saw your very quickly answer: your mathematics are very good! I will try unerstand all details. As remark, if it right, isn't neccesary say nothing about $\mu(k) \frac{e^{\mu(k)}+1}{e^{\mu(k)}-1} $, since this terms aren't in the sum, I take the sum only for $n's$ with $\mu(n)\neq 0$. Very thanks much one more time, and other more!